# I want to update status field from false to true from my firebase database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "task" : {
    "-KJ-PCQsvzADqpxnhkq7" : {
      "description" : "Hello World",
      "status" : true,
      "title" : "Hello"
    },
    "-KJ-PCoALMUCMehs0UYF" : {
      "description" : "kjkjj",
      "status" : true,
      "title" : "ghghg"
    },
    "-KJ-PCptX9r1KLIw75__" : {
      "description" : "kjkjj",
      "status" : "false",
      "title" : "ghghg"
    },
    "-KJ-PCu-xleYzZrNiy6x" : {
      "description" : "kjkjj",
      "status" : "false",
      "title" : "ghghg"
    }
  }
}
```

On click of a button I want to change the status from false to true.

```
$scope.updateTask = function(task) {
    var itemref = new Firebase("https://tasksbylima.firebaseio.com/task");
    var taskref = itemref.orderByChild("status").equalTo(true);

    taskref.on("value", function(snapshot)  {
        $scope.updateStatus = snapshot.val();
        $scope.updateStatus.child("status").update({status: "false"});
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Here's the image of Firebase database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTH6.jpg

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: ok thanks i've added the JSON structure